# Event is undefined when using dragstart

Tags: javascript, draggable

I'm trying to make elements in a list draggable but I'm running into an issue that I can't figure out. My code below follows a general format I've seen in some tutorials.

My list of draggable elements is formatted as such:

```js
function startDrag(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    console.debug(e);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag(e)"><img src="/my/image/path.svg"></li>
<li class="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="startDrag(e)"><img src="/my/image/path2.svg"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm just trying to get the `startDrag` function to fire but I keep getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

This is reproduce-able in my snippet above.

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Inline event handling attributes are not passed a reference to a DOM event and that's why your argument is `undefined`.**

[Don't use inline HTML event attributes to hook up events.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) That's a 25+ year old technique that just will not die.

Follow modern standards and use [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which will automatically be passed a reference to the DOM event that triggered the handler.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".drag").forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag);
});

function startDrag(e) {
    console.log("Drag started! Event was: ", e.type);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="drag" draggable="true">Drag me.</li>
  <li class="drag" draggable="true">No, drag me!</li>
</ul>
```